# POST when clicking an image

Tags: html, http

I have a "delete" icon with a relative position in the upper-right corner of a photo. When the icon is clicked, the photo should be deleted on the server.

According to HTTP conventions, this is a destructive action which should be done with POST. So a normal `<img href>` can not be used since it will cause a GET, which is more insecure.

What is the simplest way to make the icon perform a POST that does not exclude Internet Explorer 8? I am currently looking at:

```
<form method="post" action="script.php">
<img src="photo.jpg"/>
<input name="delete" type="image" src="/image/delete.png"/>
</form>
```

Or, is it acceptable to use a `href` in this situation?

**(EDIT: Is it more acceptable when the script is only available to an authenticated administrator?**)

Comment: You can use `Ajax` for this purpose

Comment: @Deadlock: Has it become acceptable to require JavaScript without fallbacks? Graceful degradation does not seem to apply for JavaScript anymore, seeing how Facebook and many Google services absolutely rely on it, and given reports that 99% of normal users have JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this code

```
<form method="post" action="script.php">
<button type="submit" style="background:photo.jpg"/>
<input name="delete" type="image" src="/image/delete.png"/>
</form>
```

so you can use your photo as background,because when you want submit a form you shold have a input or button whith type submit

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" name="testsubmit" value="click" 
     style="border:none; background-color:transparent;">
<img src="button.png" alt="test image submit" />
</button>
```